# Adding Firestore generates the error ld: framework not found GRPCClient

Tags: swift, firebase, grpc, google-cloud-firestore

I added Firestore to my my existing project, I have been using Realtime Database of Firebase and am having trouble to run my project again .It's now  Impossible to compile my project. I keep having  `ld: framework not found GRPCClient`.

When I remove `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'` , my project runs with no problem. But I as soon as I add `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'`  and install it I got the error with  `ld: framework not found GRPCClient`

Here is my Podfile content :

```
  pod 'Pastel'
  pod 'TwicketSegmentedControl'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManager'

  pod 'PINRemoteImage'

  pod 'FacebookCore'

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

  pod 'AAPhotoCircleCrop'
  pod 'GrowingTextView', '~> 0.4.0'
  pod 'TimeAgoInWords'

  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
```

[image: A screenshot of the build error]

Comment: Try wiping out DerivedData and rebuilding. If still having issues, share your Podfile.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I have the same issue after wiping out DerivedData and rebuilding. I edited my question with my podfile content

Comment: Are you performing 'pod install' after add this pod?

Comment: @HaroldoGondim of course I did a pod install. I was using Firebase Realtime Database, now I want to add their new NoSQL database Firestore , gRPC is one of the dependency.

Comment: You are using `MyApp.xcodeproj` or  `MyApp.xcworkspace` to open the project?

Comment: @Omkar I have been using MyApp.xcworkspace long before I decided to add Firestore to my Podfile.

Comment: I solved my issue by using .xcworkspace, you tried updating or remove and install all stuff again?

Comment: Ive cleared cocoapods cache, removing all pods from project, and installing it again, and nothing.... anyone has solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got a solution myself:

In the app workspace:

```
Target -> Project -> Build Settings
```

changing `Build Active Architectures` to `No`, also in `Pods` project, changing it in each of the targets, cleaning and re-building finally resolved `the framework not found GRPCClient` error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally update my cocoapod version, and perform the pod install to install it with the last version of cocoapod.